# How to minimize $L_1$ norm in a subspace when $L_2$ norm is fixed?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I want to solve the following optimization problem
$$\text{minimize}~~\lVert \vec{x} \rVert_1$$
$$\text{subject to}~~\lVert \vec{x} \rVert_2 = 1$$
$$\text{and}~~A \vec{x} = \vec{0}$$
where $\vec{x} \in \mathbb R^n$, $\lVert \vec{x} \rVert_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|$, $\lVert \vec{x} \rVert_2 = (\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2)^{1/2}$, $A \in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ and $m<n$. 
This is not a convex optimization problem because the domain of $\vec{x}$ is not convex. I wonder if there is any method to solve this problem, or even some method in special cases would be good.

Comment: would you mind changing the constraint into $||x||_2 \leq 1$?

Comment: @LinAlg Then the solution would be zero.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/900564/minimize-ell-1-norm-subject-to-ell-2-constraint

Comment: @WillM.: This does not work. If $A = (1 1)$, the constraint is $x_1 + x_2 = 0$. Obviously, you cannot restrict to $x_1, x_2 \ge 0$.

Comment: Ok, right. Apply Lagrange multipliers then.